# How can I appen integer to url script inline thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf, bootstrap-table

I'm using Thymeleaf and Spring Boot.
I have a table create using these scripts: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/

Then I added a javascript:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    $(function() {
        $("#list").on('click-row.bs.table',
        function(e, row, $element, field) {
            window.location = /*[[@{/url/}]]*/+row.id;
        });
    });
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

As you can see I added the `/*[[@{/url/}]]*/` to genereate the correct url, but I have to concatenate it with the id.

The problem is that it never append the id to the url.. why?
How can I fix it?

Comment: can you take html source from the page that is live, or already generated and share it here, so community can see and test your script with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put Thymeleaf Java object in some javascript variable first and then use it like you would normally do in javascript.

```
var url = /*[[@{/url/}]]*/
window.location = url + row.id;
```

From [12.2 Script inlining (JavaScript and Dart) documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart):

> Thymeleaf will execute the expression and insert the result, **but it
>   will also remove all the code in the line after the inline expression
>   itself** (the part that is executed when displayed statically).

Comment: Hi Varren, your answer is correct but not complete.
The documentation suggests adding a base template for the thymeleaf substitution to resolve static compilation error.
Ex.
var url = /*[[@{/url/}]]*/ 'theURL';